# How to add animation to UIViews inside a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, caanimation

I'm currently developing an iOS app using swift and I get some problem trying to add animations to UIViews inside a cell.

It's a menu using `UITableView` with sections.
Some of the cells can be expanded, by press a button in the cell.
The button is an arrow like ">" but pointing to the bottom , when pressed it should become up side down and the cell expand. Press it again the arrow point to bottom again and the cell shrink.I want to add an animation to it .

Animation

```
extension UIView{
    func addAnimation_rotation_x (from : Double , to : Double){
        let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
        rotationAnimation.keyPath = "transform.rotation.x"
        rotationAnimation.duration = 0.3
        rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
        rotationAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = from
        rotationAnimation.toValue = to
        self.layer.addAnimation(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }   
}
```

ViewController

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if index_of_expandedRow.contains(indexPath){
        let height = CGFloat(self.total_dishArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].expanded_rows.count) * 60 + 150
        return height
    }else{
        return 150
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DishTableViewCell") as! DishTableViewCell
    if isFinishedLoadingDishes{
//setting cells
        cell.btn_expand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(OrderViewController.expand(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        if index_of_expandedRow.contains(indexPath){
            cell.btn_expand.addAnimation_rotation_y(0, to: M_PI)
        }else{
            cell.btn_expand.addAnimation_rotation_y(M_PI, to: 0)    
        }
    }
    return cell
}

func expand (sender :UIButton){
    let cell  = sender.superview!.superview as! UITableViewCell
    let indexpath = tableView_right.indexPathForCell(cell)!
    if self.index_of_expandedRow.contains(indexpath){
        let index = self.index_of_expandedRow.indexOf(indexpath)!
        self.index_of_expandedRow.removeAtIndex(index)
    }else{
        self.index_of_expandedRow.append(indexpath)  
    }
    tableView_right.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexpath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)

//if the expanded content is not visible then make it visible

        let frame = self.tableView_right.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexpath)!.frame
        if frame.origin.y + frame.height > tableView_right.frame.height + tableView_right.contentOffset.y  {
            tableView_right.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, tableView_right.contentOffset.y + ((frame.origin.y + frame.height) - (tableView_right.frame.height + tableView_right.contentOffset.y))) ,animated:  true)
        }
    }
```

I expand the rows by changing their height.
The animation worked well when hitting the button the first time , but failed after.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: can you add cell.layoutIfNeeded() and check if it is working or not in function cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I put it before return cell, it's not working.

Comment: You can use dynamic cell height and then call layoutIfNeeded() method.

Comment: In heightForRowAtIndexPath, the height is dynamic. So where to put this layoutifNeeded()?